# In Scala, how to define a variable that is a function with a tuple argument

Tags: scala, tuples

In a Scala class, the objective is to implement a Builder pattern, and one of the arguments of the constructed class is a function that takes a tuple and returns a Double.

In the Builder class, a variable `tupleFunc` is needed to hold a function of this type with a default implementation. The Builder will also have a method `tupleFuncIs` to override the default.

```
class FunctionProblem private (val tupleFunc: (Boolean, Double, Int) => Double,
                               val func: Double => Double) {

}

object FunctionProblem {
  class Builder {
    // problem line follows
    private var tupleFunc: ((Boolean, Double, Int) => Double) = (x: (Boolean, Double, Int)) => if (x._1) x._2 else x._3.toDouble
    private var func: (Double => Double) = (x: Double) => 0.75 * x

    def tupleFuncIs(x: (Boolean, Double, Int) => Double): Builder = { tupleFunc = x; this }
    def funcIs(x: Double => Double): Builder = { func = x; this }

    def build(): FunctionProblem = new FunctionProblem(tupleFunc, func)
  }

  def builder(): Builder = new Builder
}
```

However, the Scala compiler complains of a type mismatch

```
[ant:scalac]  found   : ((Boolean, Double, Int)) => Double
[ant:scalac]  required: (Boolean, Double, Int) => Double
[ant:scalac]     private var tupleFunc: ((Boolean, Double, Int) => Double) = (x: (Boolean, Double, Int)) => if (x._1) x._2 else x._3.toDouble
[ant:scalac]                                                                                             ^
```

Why is there a double parenthesis found, or better yet, how should `tupleFunc` be rewritten to satisfy the compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need more parens

```
class FunctionProblem private (val tupleFunc: ((Boolean, Double, Int)) => Double,
  val func: Double => Double) {

}

object FunctionProblem {
  class Builder {
    // problem line follows
    private var tupleFunc: ((Boolean, Double, Int)) => Double = (x: (Boolean, Double, Int)) => if (x._1) x._2 else x._3.toDouble
    private var func: (Double => Double) = (x: Double) => 0.75 * x

    def tupleFuncIs(x: ((Boolean, Double, Int)) => Double): Builder = { tupleFunc = x; this }
    def funcIs(x: Double => Double): Builder = { func = x; this }

    def build(): FunctionProblem = new FunctionProblem(tupleFunc, func)
  }

  def builder(): Builder = new Builder
}
```

your type here

```
((Boolean, Double, Int) => Double)
```

is simply a function that takes 3 arguments not a tuple, for tuple you need to wrap it in one more `()` like this:

```
(((Boolean, Double, Int)) => Double)
```

By the way, despite having functions all over your code is not very functional, it looks a lot like java. You should maybe consider using immutable values and return new builder on midification.

My suggestion to implement this task in more scala way is to use `case class`

```
import FunctionProblem._

case class FunctionProblem(tupleFunc: TupleFunc = defaultTupleFunc, func: DoubleFunc = defaultDoubleFunc)

object FunctionProblem {
  type TupleFunc = ((Boolean, Double, Int)) => Double
  type DoubleFunc = Double => Double

  private val defaultTupleFunc: TupleFunc = x => if (x._1) x._2 else x._3.toDouble
  private val defaultDoubleFunc: DoubleFunc = 0.75 * _
}

FunctionProblem().func(3) //res0: Double = 2.25
FunctionProblem(func = _ + 5).func(3) //res1: Double = 8.0
FunctionProblem(tupleFunc = _ => 32).tupleFunc((true, 5, 1)) //res2: Double = 32.0
```

If you would like to chain calls you can use auto generated `copy` method

```
FunctionProblem().copy(func = _ + 9).copy(tupleFunc = _ => 3).func(1) //res3: Double = 10.0
```